# Error "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:__strncpy_chk" when running Spark on kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, bigdl

I am trying to run DL job on Spark on kubernetes in cluster mode, and getting error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:__strncpy_chk: symbol not found.

This is the complete error stack.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
  /tmp/dlNativeLoader8370768401448024359libiomp5.so: 
  Error relocating /tmp/dlNativeLoader8370768401448024359libiomp5.so: 
  __strncpy_chk: symbol not found
    

at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.intel.analytics.bigdl.mkl.MKL.<clinit>(MKL.java:56)
    at com.intel.analytics.bigdl.utils.Engine$.initThreadPool(Engine.scala:400)
    at com.intel.analytics.bigdl.utils.Engine$.setCoreNumber(Engine.scala:313)
    at com.intel.analytics.bigdl.utils.Engine$.setNodeAndCore(Engine.scala:470)
    at com.intel.analytics.bigdl.utils.Engine$.init(Engine.scala:124)
    at com.intel.analytics.bigdl.models.lenet.Train$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Train.scala:41)
    at com.intel.analytics.bigdl.models.lenet.Train$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Train.scala:36)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have found the docker container images on my cluster was using musl libc (alpine) linux.
And the BigDL workload required higher glibc version.
So, the system should have been ubuntu 16.04 or higher.
That solved my problem.